# Android Emulator Not working with Device Explorer

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator, android-device-explorer

Is Device Explorer will work with virtual/emulator? We are using this in physical device but upon running emulator and opening Device Explorer we get this error. Currently running on macOS Ventura.

```
Unable to access root directory of device:
sh: stat: not found
```

Comment: I've got the same.